# How to web scape table data using selenium/python for linear regression?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, linear-regression

Here is my code to scrape the table:

```
from selenium import webdriver 
    driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe")
    driver.get("https://www.baseball-reference.com/leagues/MLB/2019-standard-pitching.shtml")

    table = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="all_players_standard_pitching"]/div[3]').text
    print(table)

    driver.close()
```

I would like to parse the player's NAME, their WIN total, and their STRIKEOUT total (Name, W, SO).

I would like to use this info to run a linear regression to find out how much the variable Strikeouts influences a Pitcher's WINS.

My regression is Wins = B0 + SO(X)

I have never run a regression using Python before. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance! =)
Also, if it is not too much of an inconvenience it would be nice to graph the data as well.

Comment: Please limit to one question at a time and explain what isn't working with your current code. Indicate what the expected output would be as well and what research you have carried out in order to try and answer the problem. It will make it easier for us to help you.

Comment: @QHarr the posted code appears to be the research on the web scraping part of the question.

Comment: @JamesPhillips it’s a suggestion. It might be clearer if this question only addresses that part then. A follow-up question could deal with the regression.

Comment: @QHarr your advice is excellent, my apology. I completely agree with you.

Comment: do you really care about doing this routinely? i.e. why not just use the "Get table as CSV" option, which would give you something you could pass over to `pandas` very easily

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just had a quick look at the site and you don't need a whole browser/`Selenium` to grab the data.  the `requests` package is much easier/faster for this sort of data:

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.baseball-reference.com/leagues/MLB/2019-standard-pitching.shtml'
res = requests.get(url)

# make sure we didn't get an error
res.raise_for_status()
```

we can then use [`lxml`](https://lxml.de/) to parse the HTML:

```
from lxml import html
from lxml.cssselect import CSSSelector
from io import StringIO

doc = html.fromstring(res.content)
comment = doc.xpath(CSSSelector('div.placeholder').path)[0].getnext()
[table] = html.parse(StringIO(comment.text)).findall('//table')
```

this is a bit fiddly because they embed the data/table in a comment

now we've done that we can pull the data out:

```
results = []

for i, row in enumerate(table.xpath('//tbody//tr')):
    if 'thead' in row.get('class', ''):
        continue
    player = {}
    for cell in row.xpath('th | td'):
        key = cell.get('data-stat')
        player[key] = cell.text_content()
        columns.add(key)
    results.append(player)
```

will leave ~1000 players in `results` and in a nice form to put into a `pandas` "data frame" for easy processing:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(results)
df.set_index('ranker', inplace=True)

# convert these columns from text to numbers
for name in ('W', 'L', 'SO'):
    df[name] = df[name].astype('float')
```

once you've done this it might be worth saving it as a CSV file (or similar) you can reload later in case the website changes and you can't run the above code.  CSV is nice because lots of tools handle the format which will give you more of options later, e.g. [R](https://www.r-project.org/about.html)

I find the [`statsmodels`](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/example_formulas.html) package has the nicest interface for doing linear regressions at the moment, you could fit your question by doing:

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

fit = smf.ols('W ~ SO', df).fit()
print(fit.summary())
```

which would give you a nice summary of coefficients.  I'd discourage using a model like that though, [counts generally want to be "log transformed"](https://statmodeling.stat.columbia.edu/2019/08/21/you-should-usually-log-transform-your-positive-data/) and you'd want to do lots of plots of your data using something like `matplotlib` maybe via `seaborn`

hope that helps!

Comment: Wow @Sam Mason... You are amazing sir! Thank you so much for this thoughtful answer. I will learn a lot from this experience. =)

Answer (score 0):

To get the player's NAME from the table, I would use an XPath to find a list of elements and then handle that list on your own.

Here's the XPath:

`//table[@id='players_standard_pitching_clone']//td[@data-stat='player']`

This will get you a list of all players.

To use it, you need to call `findElements` so that you are getting a list.

`driver.findElements(by.XPath("//table[@id='players_standard_pitching_clone']//td[@data-stat='player']");`

Now you have a list of WebElements, whose text contain names. If you want to put the names into a list, you can do something like this:

```
List<IWebElement> playerNameElements = driver.findElements(by.XPath("//table[@id='players_standard_pitching_clone']//td[@data-stat='player']");
List<string> playerNames = new List<string>();

foreach (IWebElement playerElement in playerElements)
{
    playerNames.Add(playerElement.Text);
}
```

Now, `playerNames` will contain a list of strings with all of the player's names from the table.